# How does one install librets on Mac OSX Yosemite?

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite, rets

I have tried installing librets using Homebrew, but struck out.  How does one go about use the librets library on python without having to build from scratch using xcode.

Answer (score 3):

`brew tap homebrew/boneyard` then `brew edit librets` and then paste my formulae below and save first, then run `brew install librets`

Paste content below to replace old formulae (I updated to 1.6.2 so commented out old SHA1 hash as outdated)

```
require 'formula'

class Librets < Formula
  homepage 'http://code.crt.realtors.org/projects/librets'
  url 'https://github.com/NationalAssociationOfRealtors/libRETS/archive/1.6.2.tar.gz'
  #sha256 '2eaf3d163899c7f3ffa303b24d90c2e3ed4f4a92dc8b12d4d1bc4effa3962661'  (uncomment if you like)

  depends_on 'swig'
  depends_on 'boost'
  depends_on 'autoconf'

  def install
    system "./autogen.sh"
    system "./configure", "--disable-debug",
                          "--enable-shared_dependencies",
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}",
                          "--disable-dotnet",
                          "--disable-java",
                          "--disable-perl",
                          "--disable-php",
                          "--disable-ruby"
    system "make install"
  end
end
```

Comment: Note you may need to edit your permissions for `site-packages` directory. If my username was `mike` I might type the following first: `sudo chown mike:staff -R /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` so the makefile can copy the shared object to that directory.

Comment: Any updates on this? Doesn't seem to work anymore... on `brew edit librets`, I get: `Error: No available formula with the name "librets"`

Comment: @aashah7 that is a homebrew question about how to use their "boneyard" (retired formulae). Search for that but answer does mention it already.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike S. I also tried building it from the formula you provided, but I get `math.c` errors, like `no member named 'islessequal' in global namespace`.